# MonoGame - Load JSON Through the content pipeline

Tags: c#, json, monogame

I'm creating an RPG game and I need to load maps with Tiled. I have the Tiled part down (I'm using `MonoGame.Extended`). But I need extra data about the map. My plan is to use a JSON file that holds the necessary information. However, I would like to have it through the content pipeline as it is directly related to the tile maps.

I've attempted to use a custom content pipeline extension. It used `JSON.Net` to deserialize the JSON file into a `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`. However, when I compiled the DLL file and tried to reference it into the pipeline tool the pipeline tool would always crash.

Content Importer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonExtension
{

    [ContentImporter(".json", DefaultProcessor = "JsonProcessor")]
    public class JsonImporter : ContentImporter<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>
    {

        public override Dictionary<string, dynamic> Import(string filename, ContentImporterContext context)
        {
            context.Logger.LogMessage("Importing JSON file: {0}", filename);

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                return (Dictionary<string, dynamic>)serializer.Deserialize(streamReader, typeof(Dictionary<string, dynamic>));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Content Processor:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline;

namespace JsonExtension
{
    [ContentProcessor]
    public class JsonProcessor : ContentProcessor<Dictionary<string, dynamic>, Dictionary<string, dynamic>>
    {
        public override Dictionary<string, dynamic> Process(Dictionary<string, dynamic> input, ContentProcessorContext context)
        {
            context.Logger.LogMessage("Processing JSON");

            return input;
        }
    }
}
```

Content Type Writer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Compiler;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonExtension
{
    [ContentTypeWriter]
    class JsonTypeWriter : ContentTypeWriter<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>
    {
        protected override void Write(ContentWriter output, Dictionary<string, dynamic> value)
        {
            output.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }

        public override string GetRuntimeType(TargetPlatform targetPlatform)
        {
            return typeof(Dictionary<string, dynamic>).AssemblyQualifiedName;
        }

        public override string GetRuntimeReader(TargetPlatform targetPlatform)
        {
            return "JsonExtension.JsonReader";
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to store Tiled map meta-data? Or is there a better way to import it through the pipeline? Or am I doing something wrong with my content importer?

Comment: What is the error message associated with the crash?

Comment: You can add custom properties in Tiled to the map, to the layers and even to each object placed in Tiled. I use TiledSharp instead of Monogame.Extended but I am sure it also supports the usage of custom props.

Comment: `System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information` That is the error message from the content pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the `dynamic` type. The pipeline requires all types to be resolvable and instantiatable through Reflection.

There is a secondary resolver for Generic collections to Serialize and Deserialize each type in the Generic. The line `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` has two types and and unknowable type associated `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`, `System.String` and `dynamic`. The `dynamic` has no hints as to what type to use and cannot be resolved resulting in the error.

The simple solution is to store the data as a json String(which you are already doing now except the type you are attempting to store it in is `dynamic`) and Deserialize the `String` into its object after the `Content.Load` has returned the data.

In other words use `Dictionary<string, string>` as the content processor type.

---

An easier solution would be to copy the `JSON` file to the output directory. Build action "copy if newer" and use System.IO.File to read it and `JSON.NET` to deserialize it into an object in the `Initialize` method of Game1.